# my JOptionPane is not displaying for this program

Tags: java, joptionpane

This program is using while loop to make a multiplication table using only 1 dialog box 
for example 
7 times 1 is: 7,
7 times 2 is: 14,
7 times 3 is: 21,
7 times 4 is: 28 ,
but the dialog box is not displaying?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AssignmentThree
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   int result=0;
      int count4 = 1;
      String output4 = "";
      while(count4<=10)
      {
         result= 7 * count4;
         output4 += "7 times "+ count4 +" is: "+ result +"\n";
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output4);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count4` is initialized to `1` but never updated.
You therefore never exit the `while` loop.

Instead of `while`, you probably mean `for (count4=1; count4<=10; count4++)`